# Linq query mistakes class member for the group keyword

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a query as follows:

```
var resOut = from p in xRefs
            select new FileUploadRecord
            {
                group = "",
                progress = xRef.Progress,

            };
```

This will not compile, because it sees `group` as the linq group keyword, and not the member of my class.  I would simply rename the field, but it's part of a data contract and cannot be changed.

Is there a way to do this without a traditional for loop?

Comment: Use `[DataContract("group")] public string AnotherName`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `@` symbol to the beginning of the `group` property name, this allows you to use reserved/contextual keywords

```
var resOut = from p in xRefs
             select new FileUploadRecord
             {
                 @group = "",
                 ...
             }
```

Comment: I'm interested to know why this has been downvoted because it's perfectly valid code.

Comment: `group` is *not* a reserved keyword.  It is a contextual keyword.

Comment: @Servy in the context of a LINQ query it is.

Comment: No, in the context of a statement in query syntax it is still a contextual keyword, not a reserved keyword.  If it was a reserved keyword then my answer would not work, but it does.

Comment: By *reserved* I was referring to it meaning you can't use it - not from a compiler perspective. However, updated for clarity (+1 the point about your answer is a good example).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var resOut = from p in xRefs
        select new FileUploadRecord
        {
            @group = "",
            progress = xRef.Progress,

        };
```

You can escape reserved words using the `@` prefix.

Comment: OP already said that in the question: `I would simply rename the field`

Comment: @Selman22 This is **not** renaming the field, and does in fact work.

Comment: `group` is *not* a reserved keyword.  It is a contextual keyword.  There is a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use query syntax, use method syntax:

```
xRefs.Select(p => new FileUploadRecord
    {
        group = "",
        progress = xRef.Progress,
    });
```

The `group` keyword is a contextual keyword that is only considered a keyword when it is in a query syntax statement.

Comment: Why not use the LINQ syntax?

Comment: @PauloMorgado It's not LINQ syntax.  LINQ isn't a syntax.  It's query syntax.  And not using query syntax means that `group` isn't in a context in which it's a keyword.

Comment: As much as the C# team avoids introducing new keywords (contextual or not), at any point in the future other ones might be introduced. If fact, after the `LINQ` query syntax keywords introduced in C# 3.0, `dynamic` was introduced in C# 4.0 and `async` and `await` in C# 5.0. Are you also recommending not using dynamic and asynchornous methods when all it takes is a `@` prefixing the affected identifiers (§2.4.2 on the C# spec)?

Comment: @PauloMorgado LINQ is the term for a series of classes/methods in the `System.LINQ` namespace.  The syntax that you are referring to is called "query syntax" not "LINQ syntax".

Comment: @PauloMorgado And yet none of the keywords that you are referring two were breaking changes.  That's one of the important reason for adding contextual keywords (for contexts that can't exist in older versions of the language).  As for `await`, `await` isn't a breaking change because it, along with `async` are contextual keywords and it's not possible for any pre C# 5.0 program to break due to the use of identifiers with those names.

Comment: `await` is a field on a class where e new `M` method is: `async void M() { var await = false; if (await) return; var x = await Task.FromResult(0); }`

Comment: @PauloMorgado That's not a valid C# 4.0 program because the method is `async`.  The whole reason for adding the `async` keyword is that it ensures that `await` isn't a breaking change.

Comment: Só following your line of thought, I shouldn't upgrade it to C# 5.0 and use asynchronous methods. Is that it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the other answers that specify the @ are downvoted. You can use @ to define literal identifiers.

```
var resOut = from p in xRefs
        select new FileUploadRecord
        {
            @group = "",
            progress = xRef.Progress,

        };
```

See the top of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Little known fact.

Besides **verbatin identifiers** (those prefixed with `@`), Unicode escapes are permited as identifiers.

So, this would also work:

```
var resOut = from p in xRefs
select new FileUploadRecord
{
    \u0067roup = "",
    progress = xRef.Progress,

};
```

For more information, read section §2.4.2 on the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms228593.aspx).

Comment: +1 for that nifty little compiler trick, -1 for the fact that it would introduce *terrible* readability in your code.

Comment: "With Great power comes great responsibility"